# Space before star breaks syntax in ruby multiplication statement

Tags: ruby, syntax-error

While adding some whitespace to make code more readable (line up with code above it), I came across this:

```
class C
  def x
    42
  end
end
m=C.new
```

Now this will give "wrong number of arguments":

```
m.x *m.x
```

And this will give "syntax error, unexpected tSTAR, expecting $end":

```
2/m.x *m.x
```

What exactly is happening in the parser here?

I tested with Ruby 1.9.2 and 2.1.5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`*` is used for both an operator (`42 * 42`) and argument unpacking (`myfun *[42, 42]`).

When you do:

```
m.x *m.x  
2/m.x *m.x
```

Ruby interprets this as argument unpacking, rather than the `*` operator (ie. multiplication).

In case you're not familiar with it, argument unpacking (sometimes also called "splat", or "splats") means that you can have a function like this:

```
def myfun arg1, arg2; end
```

And call it like this:

```
myfun(*['Hello', 'World'])
```

`arg1` is set to `Hello`, and `arg2` is set to `World`.

I believe the rules are to determine which to use is:

- Space before but *not* after a `*` -> Argument unpacking
- Start of function parenthesis -> Argument unpacking
- Everything else -> Multiplication (or rather, the `*` operator, since Ruby does operator overloading).

Good guidelines are:

1. Use the "optional" function parenthesis when you intend argument unpacking;
2. use spaces before and after `*` when you intend the `*` operator (multiplication).

Ruby will actually warn you about this when you run `ruby -v`:

```
test.rb|11 warning| `*' interpreted as argument prefix                                    
test.rb|12 warning| `*' interpreted as argument prefix
```

Comment: Was suspecting it had something to do with this, but the error messages weren't overly helpful. +1 for ruby -v. Are the exact syntax rules for this documented somewhere?

Comment: @TrygveFlathen There's the Ruby [Ruby draft Specification here](http://www.ipa.go.jp/osc/english/ruby/ruby_draft_specification_agreement.html) (click "I agree" at the bottom), I tried to look it up, but don't have enough time right now to unravel standard-specification-language ;-)

Answer (score 3):

In simple language:

When you say

```
m.x *m.x
```

It internally calls `m.x(*m.x)` i.e it considers `*m.x` as splat argument to `m.x`.

Since, there is an `x` method defined on `m` which takes any argument(s), you are getting the "wrong number of arguments" error.

When you call

```
m.x * m.x
```

It considers `*` as a method of `x` which takes an object of type 'Fixnum' and in Ruby, the `*` method that takes an argument is defined for 'Fixnum' class. So, it's the same as calling

```
m.x.*(m.x)
```

and hence it works!

I hope that helped you understand the problem, in case any clarification is required, feel free to comment.